# How to stacktrace extlib?

Tags: error-handling, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using this brilliant piece of code to get the stacktrace in a custom error page

```
var  stackTrace = "";
    var  trace = requestScope.error.getStackTrace();
    for (var  i = 0; i < trace.length; i++){
    stackTrace += trace[i]+ "<br />" ;
}
return  stackTrace;
```

But it seem like this is not returning any extlib errors 
The following fault is only seen if I use the default runtime error page:

"Invalid component id dynC for partial refresh"

any way to modify my code to also return the extlib errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not returning extlib errors. The "invalid component id for partial refresh" error is a core runtime bug... what errors are you expecting to be reported that aren't?

Comment: Why aren't you using remote debugging capabilities instead of writing your stacktrace to the console? http://www.mindoo.de/web/blog.nsf/dx/20.07.2010094952KLEB7R.htm

Comment: @Tim this message "Invalid component id dynC for partial refresh" (dynC is dynamic content control in extlib) is reported if I use the default runtime error page. but not if I use the code above

Comment: @jjtbsomhorst don't know what you mean, I am not writing anything to the console

Comment: I guess my point is that your question asks how to return extlib errors, but the error you're referring to has nothing to do with the Extension Library. Anytime you fire a partial refresh event, and the refreshId attribute of that event specifies a component ID that doesn't exist, you'll get the error you're receiving... whether or not the Extension Library is even installed.

Comment: ok, so let me re-phrase my question, how can I make my own custom error page containg all errors I see on the default error page

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of exception is throwed. Not all exceptions have a 'getStackTrace()'. See here for more info about Xpages error management: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/error-management-in-xpages.htm. Take a look at the comment from "Dominykas Kardokas" on that page.